# Are there any statistics on the socio-economic background on affirmitive action college admissions

Tags: united-states, education, political-research, affirmative-action

I am wondering whether the affirmative action admission scholarships to college in the US handed out to minorities based on race or similar, goes to applicants from a poor background.

The reason for asking is that if the recipients of such scholarships are coming from an upper middle class background, that fairly easily could pay for a decent college, then it could be a reason for lower middle class (white) families to feel left out.

Further I assume that colleges select candidates that will actually be able to complete a degree, selecting candidates on their socio-economic background, not on their need.

Comment: I don't have a cite on hand, but recall that in Intelligence^2 debate on the topic, there was an assertion made that it goes to far more affluent demographics than is usually assumed.

Comment: Rich white people's children are far more likely to go to college than poor white people's children, and children of college graduates are far more likely to go to college, so it wouldn't be surprising if the same was true of black people. (Especially as many scholarships only cover a proportion of costs.) https://nces.ed.gov/programs/coe/indicator/cce